# How to split single line input in ruby and store it as different variable and different datatype (i.e Integer/String/Array)

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, input, split

How to split single line input into multiple variable of different data type.

#### Example

```
3 2 3 1
```

#### Sample Output

```
n = 3               #Integer/FixNum
a = [2,3,1]         #Array
```

#### To be more specific, I need

To get 3(n) times the a(input) dynamically

**like**,

```
ip -> 5 1 3 4 5 6
op -> n = 5 and a = [1,3,4,5,6]

ip -> 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
op -> n = 7 and a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

---

#### What I tried

```
a,b = gets.split(" ").map(&:to_i)  #it didn't not work

op -> a = 1, b = 2
```

Comment: You can do `a, *b = gets.split(" ").map(&:to_i)` i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use splat operator:

```
array = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
#=> [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a, *b = array # <===== magic happens here
a #=> 7
b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: `array = gets.split.map(&:to_i)` is somewhat shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = gets.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
# => [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = b.shift
# => 7
b
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```